# C# Sending request with SSL via TCP doesn't work

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl, tcp

here is my code to send TCP request coded in SSL and get the answer from server, but it doesn't work. Debugging and trying to catch exceptions didn't work.

```
public void SendRequest(string request)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int bytes = -1;

    sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request));
    bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));
}
```

I took that from stackoverflow answer so I'm suprised it doesn't work. Here is my code that receives greeting from server (it works properly):

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
StringBuilder messageData = new StringBuilder();
int bytes = 0;
bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
char[] chars = new char[decoder.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, bytes)];
decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, bytes, chars, 0);
messageData.Append(chars);

Console.Write(messageData.ToString());
```

Comment: "I took that from stackoverflow answer so I'm suprised it doesn't work." most TCP content on the web is hideously wrong. Be careful...

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: It doesn't show the answer from server, when I debug my program it stops near this line `bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);`, just stops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);` is hanging, it's because the server hasn't sent a response.

Taking a look at your code on github (linked from your other question), it looks like you are using `Console.ReadLine()` to read commands and then write them to your network stream.

What is happening is that `ReadLine()` strips off the `"\r\n"` in the string that it returns, so what you'll need to do when sending it to the server is to add back the `"\r\n"` so that the server knows that the command is finished (it waits until it gets an EOL sequence before it will respond).

What you could do is in `SendRequest()`, you could do:

```
sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request + "\r\n"));
```